# Gymnastics Lunge Position, Hand position

Tags: gymnastics

When doing a Lunge position in gymnastics, which position is the hands? I see it sometimes a) pointed in as below, b) or other times straight ahead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its best to have your arms in the position described in a).

This is because a handstand is all about balancing on your hands.

Standing in the position of b) will mean that your chest and torso will be arched. The handstand will also be arched.

Most people's head will be sticking out, so the handstand will be arching.

Your body, if it isn't arched, will be dead straight, and when your hands hit the floor, your hands are far away from the front foot. If the hands are away from the foot, it is harder to balance and the kick up will need to have more energy.

If we were doing a), the body is more or less curved in a dish shape (in the picture the gymnast should have a more round body) and therefore the head will be in, making sure that the body has a less percentage of arching over.

Also, it is easier to control where your hands are placed because you can quickly stretch out if needed or close in if needed.